# NServiceBus 5/6 Vanilla Server Crashes when changes transport to RabbitMQ

Tags: crash, rabbitmq, nservicebus

We are in the process of upgrading out 5 year old servicebus project to the latest version 5 NSB / version 6 NSB Host.  If comment out the MSMQ transport and then uncomment the rabbitmq, the project will contact rabbitmq and create the queues.  5 seconds later it crashes with no stack trace.

Either the ball was dropped in QA or I am missing something rather subtle.

The nuget for

```
NserviceBus.Transports.RabbitMQ is 2.0
RabbitMQ.Client is 3.3.5.0
NServiceBus.Host is 6.0
NServiceBus.Core is 5.0
NServiceBus.NLog is 1.0
```

A section of the app.config

```
 <connectionStrings>
   <!-- MSMQ Transport config  -->
   <!-- <add name="NServiceBus/Transport" connectionString="deadLetter=true;journal=true;useTransactionalQueues=true;cacheSendConnection=true" /> -->
  <!-- RabbitMQ Transport config  -->
  <add name="NServiceBus/Transport" connectionString="host=localhost;username=nsb;password=test;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Here is the endpoint config.  it is very simple.

```
namespace CarWash.Server
{

    [EndpointName("V4_CarWash.local")]
    public class MessageEndpoint : ServiceBusHibernateBase, IConfigureThisEndpoint
   {

      public void Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)
      {
        configuration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
        configuration.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>();

        //configuration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();
        configuration.EnableSLAPerformanceCounter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
      }

    /*   <add Messages="DiagnosticMessage" Endpoint="diagnostics.data@mdl-nsb-d"/> */
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you doing any config in ServiceBusHibernateBase ?

Comment: Also there should be a logfile in the bindir with the exception?